# C# Call generic delegates

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

So I'm trying to code a way of saving and calling delegate methods of any type. Here's some really bodged code to show what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar(){
        addEvent<Action<string>>(baz);
        callEvent<Action<string>, string>("Stuff");
    }
    List<object> fullList = new List<object>();
    void addEvent<T>(T method){
        fullList.Add(new List<T>());
        ((List<T>) fullList[0]).Add(method);
    }
    void callEvent<T1, T2>(T2 input){
        if (!typeof(T1).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(typeof(T1).Name + " is not a delegate type");
        }
        T1 method = ((List<T1>) fullList[0])[0];
        Console.WriteLine(method);
    }
    void baz(string str){
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

(I've tried using Action[object], but it /really/ didn't want to be cast to Action[string], so I abandoned that route)

Anyway. All looks good so far. But, I can't find any way at all to actually call 'method' - that last variable. What's more, C# won't allow Delegate-type constraints for T1, or allow Invoke to be called.

Can anyone think of a workaround?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: The output as it stands is " System.Action`1[System.String] "

EDIT

Nevermind. Solved my own problem. I knew all the delegates would be of the form Action[T, ...] so I just based it on that

```
public class Bar : MyClass {
    public Bar(){
        addEvent<string>(baz);
        callEvent<string>("Stuff");
    }
    List<object> fullList = new List<object>();
    void addEvent<T>(Action<T> method){
        fullList.Add(new List<Action<T>>());
        ((List<Action<T>>) fullList[0]).Add(method);
    }
    void callEvent<T>(T input){
        Action<T> method = ((List<Action<T>>) fullList[0])[0];
        method(input);
    }
    void baz(string str){
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using reflection instead of delegates?

Comment: I have, and in fact I've got a whole bunch of other stuff that uses it, but for this specifically I need to squeeze the most performance I can out of it